# Group certain rows by a value range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to group a certain records by its price range. Lets say **Customer A** bought **Product B** multiple Times as shown below figure, I want to group them together. The Below customer bought products at different price points like 800,810,830,850 etc. I want to compare each price point against others price points in the tables and see if they can grouped together.

Lets say there are ten price points

```
 800,800,850,820,830,1200,1220,1200,1250,1230.
```

I want to group numbers which are in 10% of its range. The first 5 numbers 800,800,850,820,830 are in one group and the other numbers are in a different group. How can I achieve this SQL Server?

[image: Sample Records]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want one group of:

```
min + 0.1 * (max - min)
```

for each customer as a group.  Then you want the rest in another group.  You can use window functions and arithmetic for this:

```
select t.*,
       (case when price <= 0.1 * max(price) over (partition by customer) + 0.9 * min(price) over (partition by customer)
             then 1 else 2
        end) as the_group
from t;
```